# Using ffpmeg to resample AC-3 from 23.976 fps to 24 fps

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to resample an AC-3 audio from 23.976 to 24 fps and I've tried something like this :

`ffmpeg -i TEST.ac3 -filter:a "atempo=0.999" TEST_sampled.ac3`

So I used atempo filter with 23.976/24 = 0.999. If I lauch that, it seems to work but the output is reencoded. What I want is just to resample without recoding the audio (and with no distorsion). Could you help me ?

I also tried to set 0.999 on MKVToolnix while muxing a video with that audio and it seems to work, the audio size hasn't change but I have no idea whether there are distorsions or not.

Comment: in general, no can do. Resampling requires reencoding as it modifies the data. A couple other observations: (1) why fps not sps (samples/second)? frames in audio streams are mostly artificially set by codecs and not by us end users. (b) Assuming you meant to change sampling rate, `atempo` is not a resampler (it's a speed changer) use `aresample` filter or `-ar` output option. Both of these expects the sampling rate not frame rate.

Comment: @kesh thank you for your answer but how should I use that aresample in my case ? Do you have a suggestion of command line ?

Comment: what is the actual sampling rate? Neither 24 nor 23.976 are high enough for audio sampling rate. Typically, it's above 8k: CD uses 44.1k, and DVD/BD uses 48k.

Comment: @kesh it is 48 kHz in my case

Comment: And what is the new rate you want to use?

Comment: @kesh So to sum up, the AC-3 at 48khz comes from a video at 23.976 fps and I want to sync it with a video at 24 fps. That is why I want to ajust the track like that. But I don't want to change bitrate, size and so on. And I want to do that with ffmpeg. As I said, I managed to do something like that with MKVToolnix by setting 0.999 and the track has not changed its size, bitrate.

Comment: So, you don't need to change sampling rate. What matters is then the duration of the video and audio. Is the duration of ac3 audio matches that of the 24-fps video and you know they are synced? If you so, all you need to do is: `-i video.mp4 -i audio.ac3 -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: If audio and video are not in sync, you need to use `apad` or `atrim` to align the streams.

Comment: @kesh Thanks, actually I am not sure whether I've understood : If i just mux the track with the 24 fps video it is not synced. It's only synced when I applied the factor 0.999 in MKVToolnix which I try to emulate now with ffmpeg. So the duration don't match and it seems what you suggest is just mux the 23.976 fps track with 24 fps video ?

Comment: OK, what you are describing sounds like the ac3 audio stream has an incorrect sampling rate and you are fixing it (rather than resampling it). Then `atempo` should be the right tool to use, but as stated in the first comment, you must reencode the audio stream. You need to set encoder's setup (`-b:a` likely) to specify the bitrate. The size will change because the duration will change. (You can only keep bitrate OR size the same.)

Comment: @kesh Thank you for your answer : but how come I set 0.999 in MKVToolnix then mux the audio with 24fps stream, nor size nor bitrate of that audio change (and its sync with video) ? Actually, to my mind, what I'm trying to do now with ffpmeg, e.g. set atempo = 0.999 is almost the same than in MKVToolnix but as you stated it will reencode the audio

Comment: There are so many things that you can potentially mess with in media files, and some tools go deeper than others. FFmpeg in general takes codec info as given and won't let you hack it. If you could achieve what you want with MKVToolnix (I suppose you're talking about its GUI) then you'd be better off figuring out how to use its cli tools (mkvmerge/mkvextract/etc.) to work on your file. You should be able to reproduce exact operation that way.